# Why python function in class default use "self" as the first argument to pass in

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am learning python class atm. When doing some coding experiments, a question comes up: When we using functions defined in a class, the first argument "defaultly" passed in as this object it-"self". Even I tried to rename it or swap the sequence. The first parameter still performed as "self"

Is this a golden rule in python? but why?

```py
class people:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

    def test1(k):
        return k.name

    def test2(o):
        print(o)

    def test3(i,j):
        print(i.name+j)

    def test4():
        print("test4")

    def test5(m,self):
        print(str(m)+self)

a=people('Dummy')
print(a.test1()) # "Dummy"
a.test2()        # "<__main__.people object at REFFERENCE>"
a.test2("test2") # error:test2() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
a.test3("test3") # "Dummytest3"
a.test4()        # error:test4() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
a.test5("test5") # "<__main__.people object at REFFERENCE>test5"
```

Please see my code for reference.
What I am curious about is:

1. a.test2("test2")-- intuitively I think it will come up with an output "test2" as we using a function(same as C++ class, like code below). But a default "this" already been input as the first parameter.

```
class MyClass {         
  public:               
    void myMethod(string test) {   
      cout << test;
    }
};

int main() {
  MyClass myObj;     
  string test = "testC++";
  myObj.myMethod("testC++");  
  return 0;
}
```

2. a.test5 -- I switched the "self" and parameter "m" in the function definition. Python took "m" as "this", "self" as the input parament from the function. Is this indicates the first parament has to be "this" even it is not named as "self"?

Comment: why do you need a different name?  Python is about making code that is meaningful.  do you have a better name idea?

Comment: `a.test2("test2")` and `a.test4()` fail because you didn't account for the added argument (which does not need to be named `self`).

Comment: when you use `a.test1()` then Python runs `people.test1(a)` so it assigns `a` to first variable. Even you can run `people.test1(a)` and it will work.

Comment: It's not a rule, it's a convention. Your `test1` and `test3` are totally valid. P.S. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you're wrong that you can't change it: you can use whatever parameter name you like.  `self` is merely convention, parallel to `this` in other languages -- although some have `this` as a pre-defined or reserved word.

For instance:

```
class Dummy():
    def __init__(this):
        this.name = "self"
        this.value = 0

thing = Dummy()
print(thing.name, thing.value)
```

Output:

```
self 0
```

However, Python *does* mandate the semantics of the first argument to any instance method: that argument is, by language definition, the instance that invokes the method.  Doing so ensures that you have ready access to the calling instance in a known, stable location for any such method in the class.

Comment: a lot of people would understand the class code if the name for the object reference in the method definition was `this`, but it would slow down the reading because the majority of them would have to double-check the definition.  people accustomed to reading python code expect `self` to be used.

Comment: @Skaperen A lot of other languages (eg Perl) use `self` instead of `this`. It doesn't really matter what keyword you use it would still confuse people not used to OO or came from a language with implicit `this` (eg Java). Look at how many questions about what `this` is (not how it works) in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The use of 'self' is tied to the fact that any object method in Python automatically passes in the object itself as the first parameter. The convention is to name it 'self' so there is no confusion as to what the first parameter is. You can use another name, but it will make your code at odds with the vast majority of Python code that exists.